# How to add a button to the bottom of a Table View in order to delete multiple rows?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button

I am currently in the process of creating a library app. I have a table view and I have already set up the cells with an array of different book names. I have also set up checkmarks so that the user can checkmark certain titles. I have just added a button to the bottom of the table view so that the user can checkmark titles and then click the button in order to remove them from the screen, kind of like checking them out. However the button does not click for some reason and the titles do not get removed from the screen either. I have looked at many other responses on this site and I have even tried a couple, but none of them seem to work. Could someone please point me in the right direction? I am posting my current code below.

```
import UIKit

class CheckOutViewController: UITableViewController {
    var books = ["The Grapes of Wrath","The Great Gatsby","Anthem","Brave New World","To Kill A Mockingbird","Of Mice And Men", "Animal Farm", "War and Peace", "Don Quixote","War and Peace","Romeo and Juliet","Gulliver's Travels"]

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return books.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = books[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        }
        else{
            tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        }
    }

    @IBAction func checkOutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
            func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
            {
                if editingStyle == .delete
                {
                    books.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }

            return true
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's with all of the incorrectly nested functions inside `checkOutPressed`?

Comment: Oh sorry that is not my own code. That is one of the solutions that I found for this problem, and I was trying it, and it didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Post valid code.

Comment: At least *try* to understand the solution you are trying. Do you know how it works?

Comment: It's just really weird because the button doesn't click in this table view, but the buttons in my other view controllers work just fine, so I have no clue what to do.And I'm still trying to figure out how to delete the multiple rows with that button.

Comment: I think I understand it relatively well.

Comment: I am just really confused on how to solve this problem, so if anybody could guide me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to maintain a array of indexpath like :

```
    var arrTodelete = [IndexPath]()
```

and do some change in cellforIndexPath :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellNew", for: indexPath)
    ....  
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    if arrTodelete.contains(indexPath){
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }else{
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }..... }
```

and didselect code :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if arrTodelete.contains(indexPath){
        let index = arrTodelete.index(of: indexPath)
        arrTodelete.remove(at: index!)
    }else{
        arrTodelete.append(indexPath)
    }

    tblView.beginUpdates()
    tblView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    tblView.endUpdates()
}
```

and finally when u click on Delete Button :

```
@IBAction func checkOutPressed(_ sender: Any) {

 for ele in arrTodelete{
        books.remove(at: ele.item)
    }

    tblView.beginUpdates()
    tblView.deleteRows(at: arrTodelete, with: .fade)
    tblView.endUpdates()

    arrTodelete.removeAll()
    tblView.reloadData() }
```

Do these things and it'll work a/c to you ..

Comment: Hi I inputted the code that you gave me, but it has given me the error Thread 1 Fatal Error: Index out of range at the arr.remove(at: ele.item).Do you know by chance why that might be happening?

Comment: just update arr with books ... and then check or just look i have updated the answer also

Comment: Thank you.Quick question, what does the ele mean in that for statement? What does it do?

Comment: here we are iterating array of indexpath so ele is a indexpath